# Найти отсутствующее число в последовательности / множестве натуральных чисел

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

У меня задача взять несортированный массив уникальных номеров от 1 до n и вывести числа, которые отсутствуют в этом диапазоне.

В конце задания написано:  *В массиве ни одно число не пропущено, или отсутствует ровно одно число. Можете найти его за O(N) времени? Подсказка: Можно использовать «Умную формулу».*

Я полез в интернет посмотреть что за O(N) time, и оказалось это Временная сложность алгоритма, но я не понял как его реализовать.

PS: у меня если при итерации ничего не произошло должно вывести undefined

```js
function missing(arr) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => { return a - b })

    let missingNum = []

    for(let i = 1; i < Math.max.apply(null, arr); i++) {
        let searched = arr.includes(i)

        if(searched !== false) {
            continue
        }

        missingNum.push(i)
    }

    if(missingNum.length === 0) {
        return undefined
    }

    return missingNum.join(', ')
}

console.log(missing([]))
console.log(missing([1, 4, 3]))
console.log(missing([2, 3, 4]))
console.log(missing([5, 1, 4, 2, 70]))
console.log(missing([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: намекаю, вам нужен аналог HashSet (хз как он в js назыается) или вы можете использовать  сортировку подсчетом, если n достаточно мало.

Comment: Если говорится о хитрой формуле, то есть подозрение, что в условии вы кое-что могли упустить.

Comment: вот полное описание: missing - Takes an unsorted array of unique numbers (ie. no repeats) from 1 through some number n, and returns the missing number in the sequence (there are either no missing numbers, or exactly one missing number). Can you do it in O(N) time? Hint: There’s a clever formula you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clever formula":

`(n + 1) * n / 2`

Comment: как это понять?

Comment: @Mageeka Сумма чисел от одного до `n`. Одного не хватает. Как найти - какого?

Comment: посмотрел в гугле, пишут что это формула Гауса

Comment: @Mageeka и что?

Comment: я не могу понять при чем она, к этой задаче

Comment: @Mageeka Числа от 1 до n образуют арифметическую прогрессию, данная формула - её сумма, разница с реальной суммой - пропущенное число.

Comment: @MBo иногда я поражаюсь своей тупости, но насколько мне подсказывает логика, это верно если пропущено только одно число

Comment: @Mageeka  Так в точном условии и говорится  `(there are either no missing numbers, or exactly one missing number).`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function missing(arr) {
  let all = [];
  all.length = arr.length? Math.max.apply(null, arr) : 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    all[i] = i + 1;
  arr.forEach(i => all[i - 1] = -1);
  let missingNum = all.filter(i => i != -1);

  return missingNum.length ? missingNum.join(', ') : undefined;
}

console.log(missing([]))
console.log(missing([1, 4, 3]))
console.log(missing([2, 3, 4]))
console.log(missing([5, 1, 4, 2, 70]))
console.log(missing([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: простите за неудобный вопрос, но ваш код быстрее моего?

Comment: @Mageeka да *(4 символа нужно...)*

Comment: если Вам не сложно, можете объяснить почему, мне пока трудно понимать код

Comment: @Mageeka Потому что мой код O(N), a Ваш O(N^2).

Comment: это потому, что у меня метод sort?

Comment: @Mageeka (Пора выяснить временную сложность сортировки.) Нет, потому что Вы в цикле вызываете `includes`.